# Exercise from G. De Barra - *Measure Theory and Integration*

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

This is my first post in *Measure Theory*::

Let $\{I_n\}_{{n}}$ be a finite sequence of open intervals which covers the set of all rationals in $[0,1]$.

> Show that $\sum_{n} l(I_n)\ge1$.

In order to show this I think that I have to show that if $\{I_n\}$ covers $\Bbb Q\cap [0,1]$ then it covers $[0,1]$. Then  my monotonicity of outer measure function we have $\sum_{n}l(I_n)>1$.

Now it is enough to show that $\{I_n\}_{{n}}$ covers $\Bbb Q^c\cap [0,1]$.

Let $i$ be an irrational number such that $I_n$ does not cover $i$ for any $n\in \Bbb N$.Let $r_n$ be an enumeration of rational numbers such that $r_n<i<r_{n+1}$

But I can't arrive at a contradiction from here?

Any help will be great.

Comment: If you include $\emptyset$ as an interval (I do and the general definition does), this is false.

Comment: Maybe it should be *open* intervals?

Comment: It should be a *finite* sequence, and the inequality need not be strict.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese ??? I'm missing your point - what he says he wants to prove is false whether or not we include $\emptyset$ as an interval...

Comment: @GenericNickname No, it's false for open intervals...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I was thinking $I_1 = [0, 1]$, $I_n = \emptyset$ for $n \geq 2$. I agree though that the inequality fails even if the intervals are non-empty; the standard argument which shows that there is an open set of arbitrarily small measure containing the rationals can be applied here.

Comment: This is false. Take $(a_k)_k$ an enumeration of the rationals in [0;1], for each $a_k$ take $I_k$ to be the interval of lenght $\varepsilon/2^k$ centered in $a_k$. You obtain a covering of $\mathbb Q \cap [0;1]$ and the total lenght of the intervals can be as small as you want. So maybe the exercice is about the set of all IRrational ?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich;@David Question edited

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese;Question edited

Comment: What exactly is $l(I_n)$?

Comment: The revised version is true. But you're not going to be able to prove it by showing that the intervals cover all of $[0,1]$; that need not be so. (Say $i\in(0,1)$ is irrational. Consider the two open intervals $(-1,i)$ and $(i,2)$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1] \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^k I_n$$

$$\overline{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]} \subseteq \overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^k I_n}= \bigcup_{n=1}^k \overline{I_n}$$

$$1=m[0,1]=m(\overline{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]})\le m(\bigcup_{n=1}^k \overline{I_n})\le \sum_{n=1}^k l(\overline{I_n})=\sum_{n=1}^k l(I_n) $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: One of the intervals contains $0$. Say that interval is $(a_0,b_0)$. So $a_0<0<b_0$. If $b_0\ge1$ you're done. Assume $b_0<1$.

Choose a sequence of rationals $r_k$ that decrease to $b_0$. Each $r_k$ is in one of the remaining intervals. *Since* there are only finitely many intervals, at least one of the remaining intervals contains infinitely many $r_k$. Say $(a_1,b_1)$ contains infinitely many $r_k$. Then $a_1\le b_0$ and $b_1>b_0$...

Comment: Well I'm certain you don't want me to just do it for you... Think about it. What about $a_2$ and $b_2$?

Comment: really nice construction! thank you @David